# Dataset vs table adapter?

Tags: c#, data-access-layer

what is difference between dataset and table adapter can someone explain with interesting example please.

How does table adapter gets data from sql server ?

Comment: This is too vague and too broad for this site. You need to look for a tutorial.

Comment: what kind of tutorial sir

Comment: A `TableAdapter` is just a strongty typed class that holds an `DataAdapter` which holds select-,insert,update- and delete commands. So you can use it to fill a (strongy typed) DataTable/DataSet or to update data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx

Comment: Like [this](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Dataset+table-adapter+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `DataAdapter` to fill the `DataSet` with the data from SqlServer.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_tblname", conn);

try
{

     conn.Open();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
     da.SelectCommand = cmd; // Set the select command for the DataAdapter
     da.Fill(ds); // Fill the DataSet with the DataAdapter
     DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // I just displayed the results in a grid view for simplicity.  If Asp.Net you will have to call a DataBind of course.

catch (Exception ex)
{
     conn.Close();
     conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Tables[0] might not be tbl_tblname as you assumed.